# Build a Zoom Clone with Node JS (peer to peer connection)

Tags: node.js, webrtc, peer, peerjs

I have tried to create zoom clone using nodejs i have successfully displayed my video in the web page and created id for each person joining the link but while displaying the joined person in the main page is not working.

I'm use peerjs library to call the user and display him in the web page.

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const server = require('http').Server(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(server);

const {v4:uuidv4} = require('uuid');

const { ExpressPeerServer} = require('peer');

const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
    debug:true
});

const { response } = require('express');

app.use('/peerjs',peerServer);

app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'))


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(`/${uuidv4()}`);
})


app.get('/:room',(req, res)=>{
    res.render('room',{ roomId:req.params.room })
})

 io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('join-room' , (roomId,userId) => {
        socket.join(roomId);
        socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-connected',userId);
     })
})

server.listen(3035);
```

**room.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Zoom CLone</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        const ROOM_ID = "<%= roomId %>"
    </script>
    <style>
        #video-grid{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;

        }
        video{
            height: 300px;
            width: 400px;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="video-grid"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
const socket = io('/')
const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid');
const myVideo=document.createElement('video');
myVideo.muted = true;

var peer = new Peer(undefined, {
    host:'/',
    port:'3031'
})
// const peer = new Peer(undefined, {
//     path: '/peerjs',
//     host: '/',
//     port: '3001'
//   })

peer.on('open',id => {
    socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id);
})

let myVideoStream
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video:true,
    audio:true
}).then(stream => {
    myVideoStream=stream;
    addVideostream(myVideo,stream)

    peer.on('call', call => {
        call.answer(stream)
        const video = document.createElement('video')
        call.on('stream',userVideoStream => {
            addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
        })
    })
    socket.on('user-connected',(userId) => {
        connectToNewUser(userId, stream);
    })
})


  
const connectToNewUser = (userId, stream) => {
    const call = peer.call(userId, stream)
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
        addVideostream(video, userVideoStream)
    })
    call.on('close', () => {
      video.remove()
    })
}

const addVideostream = (video,stream) =>{
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',() => {
        video.play();
    })
    videoGrid.append(video);
}
```

there is also no error in the code, I also checked in the console.
Only problem is the person connected with the link video is not displayed on the main(Host) page.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on the same project and I figured that the reason why when the user joins the channel, his/her video wont be showing on the host screen is because of `audio: true` present in the getUserMedia in script.js.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video:true,
    audio:true
})
```

So if you change it to false, that problem will be solved and the second person's video also will be seen there but then another problem will arise, which is that you wont be able to communicate via audio. I haven't figured out the solution to this, but if anyone else figure it out, then do tell me.

Comment: Thank you! This is very strange but your solution actually helped me. I still don't understand the problem at all, I've even tried to look into the URL's that peer clients used to connect to the other client and they all seem correct. It's strange that the call never goes through. Have you by any chance figured out the reason yet?

Comment: No, I still haven't solved it yet. If you find the solution, do tell me.

Comment: As of now, I try to refresh the page until the client actually joins the room and the peer calls go through, I still don't know what the problem is. Also, I don't face this issue when I host it locally using the webpack server (with proxy to my express server) which comes with the react-scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine it has no error but in your **script.js** you need to include

> path : "/peerjs"

and port number should be same on which server is listening therefor it should be 3035 instead 3031, your code should look like this:

```
var peer = new Peer(undefined, {
  path: "/peerjs",
  host: "/",
  port: "3035",
});
```

Also try removing this lines on your **connectToNewUser** function

```
call.on('close', () => {
      video.remove()
    })
```

And sometimes it happens due to poor internet connection so you need to keep refreshing your browser to see the changes on live video.

hope this help. For more info on **peerjs library** check its official [website](https://peerjs.com/).

I have created similar project where I have same code with extra features you can refer to my [git repository](https://github.com/Div685/Zoom-Clone) to compare your code.

Answer (score 0):

change
peer port:"3031"
to
port:"443"
or something else
then when you deploy it to online server it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

I may be late but i confronted the same problem
try changing

```
socket.on('user-connected',(userId) => {
    connectToNewUser(userId, stream);
})
```

})

with

```
 socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
    // user is joining`
    setTimeout(() => {
    // user joined
    connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
    }, 1000)
    })
})
```

that worked for me